# Hacer llamada a la API REST de paypal aregando un array

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

lo que pretendo es en mi metodo de payment aregar un array con algunas cosas que después de que realice el pago el usuario utilizar esa información del array para guardar en la base de datos.

actualmente así esta armado mi payment pero le deseo agregar el el array como el de links pero para ids que despues ocupare para consultar en la base de datos como de productos, direcciones del usuario o direcciones de tiendas, se supone que la dirección de envió no debe de cambiar es por eso que en ese array deceseo traer todos sus campos para evitar fraude de parte del usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿y para qué quieres guardar el array en la variable que contiene el payment de PayPal?, entiendo que lo quieres usar pero, ¿por qué tiene que estar añadida dentro de esa clase?, si te refieres a usar el array una vez que el pago fue aprobado, pues guarda tus datos en sesión: `session(['array_datos' => $tu_array]);` Y una vez que ya completaste todo sólo eliminas la variable de la sesión: `session()->forget('array_datos')`.

Comment: Es como lo tengo actualmente , pero si por alguna extraña razón en el transcurso de el pago y el registro en mi base de datos la dirección de envío la sección le pasa algo no tendría forma de recuperar esa información en cambio si pasa eso con el Id de pago de paypal puedo volver a consultar todo